# How to retrieve all url_like by user filtered by url

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the next code to retrieve url likes about the user,

This is my like button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="400"
        data-show-faces="false" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/profile/ttt"
        style="margin:4px"></div>
```

This box works, i can see the like when i do like,

but when i get the likes about the user... with the next code

```
    FB.api(
                                        {
                                            method :     'fql.query',
                                            query :     "SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() AND strpos(url,'http://mypage/subpage') = 0"
                                        },
                                        function(response) {
                                            console.log(response);
                                        });
                    });
```

the response not shows all likes or not shows my url likes (https://stackoverflow.com/profile/ttt)... i dont know why? i need help to  understand that..

regards,

**UPDATE**: I CAN RESOLVE WITH "SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() AND strpos(url,'https://stackoverflow.com/users/439368/jrey-py') = 0 limit 99999"

but i dont know if this is the best way,

Comment: http://mypage/subpage = the like data-href

Comment: Have you had the user login to your app _and_ grant `user_likes` permission first …?

Comment: I can resolve adding limit 9999999 to my query, thanks